# SSL Not working on Xammp

Tags: xampp, virtualhost, host

By default, im using this on virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost www.somedomain.com:443> 
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/www.somedomain.com"
    ServerName www.somedomain.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@www.somedomain.com
    ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
    <IfModule log_config_module>
        CustomLog "logs/access.log" combined
    </IfModule>

    SSLEngine on 
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
    SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|pl|asp|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/www.somedomain.com">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    CustomLog "logs/ssl_request.log" "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
```

And already included it in my windows host file.

But it keeps on saying:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with message 'Unable to Connect to ssl://www.google.com:443. Error #127380504: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
```

'

I've been lookinh for solutions for several hours now.

Answer (score 0):

The error obviously is from a PHP application that uses the Zend framework. Here are the possibilities

- URL ssl:// is not valid should be more like https:// but I could be wrong here, I am not very experienced with Zend Gdata framework.
- CURL doesn't have SSL support in xampp.
- Check your PHP.ini file to see if ssl support is enabled.

Realising that Xampp is very easy to get going on Windows, you might want to give vanilla Apache + PHP a go and see if you can replicate the problem.